# Fedora 25 live does not allow persistent mode

Tags: fedora, persistence

I downloaded Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3 and wrote it to a USB using [Multisystem](http://liveusb.info/) because I am already using LinuxMint on the same USB. I can boot both but can't make Fedora persistent while I can do so with Linux Mint. When I try to make persistent mode a message shows saying that iso doesn't allow persistent mode. What is the reason? Which Fedora ISO file should I get then?

Answer (score 2):

Fedora doesn't have support for this mode. This mode is optional and it's avaliability varies from distro to distro.

That dorsn't mean it's impossible though, but I have only a very vague idea on how to modify the image.